# How to link images with texts in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make an app that display a text for each image, I have imported four images and four text views , but when i press on any of the image it is display the same text. and display the 4 texts in the same time

how to display a different text with each image. (i am working in the Main2Activity)

xml code

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="WELCOME "
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:checked="true"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="ANDROID"
    android:id="@+id/t3"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/t4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:checked="false"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="STUDIO"
    android:id="@+id/t4"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
    android:checked="false"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="TO"
    android:id="@+id/t2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:checked="false"/>
```

JAVA CODE

public class Main2Activity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView t1,t2,t3,t4, textview;

```
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.text);
    t1.setOnClickListener (this); //here you're setting onClickListener to listen for taps
    textview = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.t1);
    t2.setOnClickListener (this);
    textview = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.t2);
    t3.setOnClickListener (this);
    textview = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.t3);
    t4.setOnClickListener (this);
    textview = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.t4);
}

@Override
public void onClick (View v) { //this is an implementation of OnClickListener interface
    switch (v.getId ()){ //here you're reading id of the taped button and doing something depending on what TextView taped
        case R.id.t1:
            t1.setText ("leo");
            break;
       case R.id.t2:
           t2.setText ("mike");
            break;
        case R.id.t3:
            t3.setText ("raph");
            break;
        case R.id.t4:
            t4.setText ("don");
            break;
    }}}
```

Comment: Try using   android:drawableLeft="image path" and same if you want to use right

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement View.OnClickListener in your activity where TextViews are declared. Code should look somehow like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.t1);
    t1.setOnClickListener (this); 

    t2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.t2);
    t2.setOnClickListener (this);

    t3 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.t3);
    t3.setOnClickListener (this);

    t4 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.t4);
    t1.setOnClickListener (this);
}

@Override
public void onClick (View v) { //this is an implementation of OnClickListener interface
    switch (v.getId ()){ //here you're reading id of the taped button and doing something depending on what TextView taped
        case R.id.t1:
            t1.setText ("leo");
            break;
       case R.id.t2:
           t2.setText ("mike");
            break;
        case R.id.t3:
            t3.setText ("raph");
            break;
        case R.id.t4:
            t4.setText ("don");
            break;
    }}}
```

If you have more then one TextView then you need to .setOnClickListener(this) on every of them

Comment: can you check what i change, because it is display no text when i press on the image.did i change wright or need to fixed.,,, sorry im new in android studio

Comment: I've edited my answer to fully fit your code, use it.

Comment: i copied your code, but  still same problem no text (empty page). no error in the code everything is good ,,,,, also it shows me (no tests were found) is this the reason??      this is the massege.......                                                                                                                              Running tests
Test running startedFinish
Empty test suite.

Comment: @samawi, that's because you're starting tests, but not the app. Just hit Shift + F10 and that should run app compilation